# How to slow down the speed of a mapreduce job

Tags: mapreduce

I have a map reduce job. 
I have used

```
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
```

to control its speed.
Is there any other way to slow down the speed of the job.
We are afraid that the job running too fast may affect our database.

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit the queues supported in yarn. For instance you can create a queue with appropriate restrictions over memory and cpu cores and then set your job configurations to use that queue for launching map reduce job.
I would suggest you go through the following documentation on [fair scheduler](http://doc.mapr.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/26982625).

For your current solution of setting numReducers = 0,  I think that it might not be the best way to restrict the compute.